# MySQL-Show, for each year, the largest department in that year, and its average salary

Tags: mysql

According to this question, the output should be like ' per year the largest department and then in that department average salary'. In MySQL database, there is 'from_date' and 'to_date' column in the salary and dept_emp table. And there is no any specific year that contains the exact year for required largest department and salary.

In my query below, it returns same year two or more times. But I need just per year the largest department and its avg_salary. But I`m not sure which date I have to take to retrieve the right result.

Note: in the salary table -'from_date' is about the for one person which starts to get a salary from that year to 'to_date' year. And in the dept_emp table, 'from_date' is about of per person`s beginning of work year to 'to_date'. Besides these dates, there is no addition date.

I want to give an example to clarify the question:

for example the year 2000, deptartment-Finance, Number of emp-34000- avg_salary-56700. In the 2000 the largest department was Finance and in that department avg salary was 56700.

Thanks in advance for your help :)

```
SELECT 
dept_name AS Department_Name,
COUNT(de.emp_no) AS Number_of_Employees,
YEAR(s.from_date) AS Year,
AVG(salary) AS Average_Salary
FROM
dept_emp de
    JOIN
departments d ON de.dept_no = d.dept_no
    JOIN
salaries s ON de.emp_no = s.emp_no
GROUP BY YEAR(s.from_date)
```

Comment: See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query

Comment: Is that unclear? if it is , I`ll try to make it better

Comment: I really wouldn't have bothered providing the link if I didn't think it would be useful

Answer (score -1):

Why don't you try with adding a MAX clause on the Number_Of_Employees column ?

```
    SELECT 
dept_name AS Department_Name,
MAX(COUNT(de.emp_no)) AS Number_of_Employees,
YEAR(s.from_date) AS Year,
AVG(salary) AS Average_Salary
FROM
dept_emp de
    JOIN
departments d ON de.dept_no = d.dept_no
    JOIN
salaries s ON de.emp_no = s.emp_no
GROUP BY YEAR(s.from_date)
```

Comment: It doesn`t work for me, I got error like ' invalid use of group function('